# How to turn off the LCD while taking long-exposure photos?

Tags: canon, long-exposure, lcd, backlight, chdk

I'm using a Canon SX210 IS with CHDK. I know that capturing long exposition photos is a "battery draining" process, but it could be better. Why should the LCD's backlight be on while taking the photo? It might be a bug of CHDK. Otherwise, does anybody know how to turn the backlight off??

Comment: If you can't turn it off - did you try reducing the LCD brightness to its lowest value?

Comment: Yes, that's what I do, and is the closesto thing to turn it off.

Comment: is this really a photography question? Seems more like a technical user manual for a piece of equipment question...?

Comment: @andy: It is a camera question, specifically dealing with battery lifetime. We do more hardware related questions here than anything, so given precedent, it fits. That said, this is really more of a CHDK question, which really probably fits better on the CHDK wiki or forums than here. I don't know if there is a hard reason for either keeping or or closing it, so I've left it up to the community. So far, it seems like the community wants to keep it: no close votes, and 5 up votes.

Comment: @andy: The term "Photography", involves a lot of things. Since cameras hardware, to art. So, I think my question is not out of topic. jrista is right, this might have been better asked in the CHDK forums, but I asked here first, in case somebody knows.

Comment: We have had a few CHDK questions in the past, and they are well accepted here. Feel free to ask them in the future, as we most certainly cover hardware and firmware here as well as "photography".

Comment: hey guys... fair enough. I'm not much of a question closer anyways as I think sometimes people are quite harsh. However, I must say, with the amount of purely technical questions popping up on the site that don't enrich photographic knowledge, I do find myself not wanting to post questions on this site... and would rather go to flickr, even though the software is horrible. It's that stuff Jeff Atwood talks about in terms of community in that the questions asked are as important as the questions not asked. You don't want to dilute the community... just my current thoughts...?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you press the DISP button to cycle through the various display options, one of which is off.

No experience with CHDK, but that's how regular Canons work.

**Editing much later to add:** I have since installed CHDK on my S90, and the DISP button works the same as with the stock firmware. So simply pressing it should cycle you through basic display, extended info display, and display off.